# what's wrong with this last >{\centering}p{1.0cm}?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, arrays

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, UTF8, scheme = plain, twoside]{ctexart}
%%
%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=1.68cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%
%%
\begin{document}
%%
%%
\begin{center}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\Large
\begin{tabular}{| >{\centering}p{5.8cm} | >{\centering}p{1.8cm} | 
>{\centering}p{1.0cm} | 
>{\centering}p{1.0cm} |
>{\centering}p{1.0cm} |
>{\centering}p{1.0cm} | 
    c | % works with   c|
}
\toprule
\textbf{PaperName} & 
\textbf{Page} & 
\textbf{A} & 
\textbf{B} & 
\textbf{C} & 
\textbf{D} & 
\textbf{E} \\
\midrule
    \verb=9709_s21_ms_13= & 1     & 59 & 51 & 42 & 32  & 22 \\
    \verb=9709_s21_ms_12= & 17    & 63 & 54 & 44 & 34  & 23 \\
    \verb=9709_s21_ms_11= & 33    & 61 & 50 & 41 & 31  & 21 \\
    \verb=9709_s20_ms_13= & 49    &    &    &    &     &    \\
    \verb=9709_s20_ms_12= & 67    &    &    &    &     &    \\
    \verb=9709_s20_ms_11= & 81    &    &    &    &     &    \\
    \verb=9709_s19_ms_13= & 97    & 62 & 54 & 44 & 34  & 24 \\
    \verb=9709_s19_ms_12= & 111   & 65 & 54 & 43 & 31  & 19 \\
    \verb=9709_s19_ms_11= & 127   & 65 & 57 & 47 & 37  & 28 \\
    \verb=9709_s18_ms_13= & 146   & 62 & 55 & 45 & 35  & 25 \\
    \verb=9709_s18_ms_12= & 164   & 62 & 52 & 42 & 32  & 21 \\
    \verb=9709_s18_ms_11= & 182   & 62 & 54 & 44 & 34  & 24 \\
    \verb=9709_s17_ms_13= & 199   & 49 & 41 & 32 & 23  & 13 \\
    \verb=9709_s17_ms_12= & 214   & 51 & 42 & 31 & 21  & 10 \\
    \verb=9709_s17_ms_11= & 232   & 55 & 46 & 37 & 28  & 18 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{center}
%%
\end{document}
```

For the last colum, if I used

```
>{\centering}p{1.0cm} | 
>{\centering}p{1.0cm} |
>{\centering}p{1.0cm} |
>{\centering}p{1.0cm} | 
>{\centering}p{1.0cm} | % works with   c|
```

instead, it will give me an error......

> > \midrule ->\noalign
> > {\ifnum 0=`}\fi @aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global @...

why? how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\centering` redefines `\\`  to be a centred newline, breaking the `tabular` use ,you can use `\centering\arraybackslash` to restore the array/tabular `\\`

Alternatively and possibly better since it looks like your table cells are not really multi-line paragraphs use the fixed width form of `c` so `wc{1cm}` rather than `p{1cm}` for all the columns. (Requires an `array` package that's not too old)

Answer (score 4):

Either use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}` for the last column or let TeX do the computations:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  UTF8,
  scheme = plain,
  twoside,
  fontset = windows % because otherwise it doesn't work on macOS
]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[
  top=0.5cm,
  left=0.5cm,
  right=0.5cm,
  bottom=1.68cm,
  showframe % <--- remove from production version
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\Large

\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{
  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}
  *{7}{c}
  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
}
\toprule
\textbf{PaperName} & 
\textbf{Page} & 
\textbf{A} & 
\textbf{B} & 
\textbf{C} & 
\textbf{D} & 
\textbf{E} \\
\midrule
    \verb=9709_s21_ms_13= & 1     & 59 & 51 & 42 & 32  & 22 \\
    \verb=9709_s21_ms_12= & 17    & 63 & 54 & 44 & 34  & 23 \\
    \verb=9709_s21_ms_11= & 33    & 61 & 50 & 41 & 31  & 21 \\
    \verb=9709_s20_ms_13= & 49    &    &    &    &     &    \\
    \verb=9709_s20_ms_12= & 67    &    &    &    &     &    \\
    \verb=9709_s20_ms_11= & 81    &    &    &    &     &    \\
    \verb=9709_s19_ms_13= & 97    & 62 & 54 & 44 & 34  & 24 \\
    \verb=9709_s19_ms_12= & 111   & 65 & 54 & 43 & 31  & 19 \\
    \verb=9709_s19_ms_11= & 127   & 65 & 57 & 47 & 37  & 28 \\
    \verb=9709_s18_ms_13= & 146   & 62 & 55 & 45 & 35  & 25 \\
    \verb=9709_s18_ms_12= & 164   & 62 & 52 & 42 & 32  & 21 \\
    \verb=9709_s18_ms_11= & 182   & 62 & 54 & 44 & 34  & 24 \\
    \verb=9709_s17_ms_13= & 199   & 49 & 41 & 32 & 23  & 13 \\
    \verb=9709_s17_ms_12= & 214   & 51 & 42 & 31 & 21  & 10 \\
    \verb=9709_s17_ms_11= & 232   & 55 & 46 & 37 & 28  & 18 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't add vertical rules if you use `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`. Actually, it's best to *never* use vertical rules in tables.